# WPF Windows 7 Lock Screen Buttons

Tags: wpf, windows-7, styles

In Windows 7 (and Vista, if I recall correctly), when you hit CTRL+ALT+DELETE it takes you to a pre-lock screen such as the following:

[image: Windows 7 Lock Screen]

I am looking to find a way to recreate the buttons on this screen (Lock this computer, Switch User, etc.) for an app I am working on. I need to be able to specify what the left-hand side image is since all of mine won't be arrows. Does anyone know where I can find a style that mimics how this looks/behaves?

Also, if there is a way to also come up with a button style that mimics the Cancel one that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrayson/archive/2007/02/16/creating-a-glass-button-the-complete-tutorial.aspx) and you should get the cancel button style. And for the other buttons you can create a [button](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties) `ControlTemplate` with a `StackPanel` containing `Image` and `TextBlock`.

Comment: The tutorial is perfect - exactly what I'm looking for. I toyed with the ControlTemplate option (and even had a working demo), but it looked really flat. The buttons in 7 are much more aesthetically pleasing which is why I was trying to replicate the style of those. I might be able to use that tutorial and tweak it a bit to get the style I'm looking for though.